# Moving an object with a file descriptor

Tags: c++

I have a class, say `Foo`, defined like this:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(int i) {
    valid = false;
    char devname[] = "/dev/device0";
    sprintf(devname, "/dev/device%d", i);
    fd = open(devname, O_RDWR);
    if (fd > 0) {
      valid = true;
    }

  ~Foo() {
    if (valid) {
      close(fd);
    }
  }

  bool valid;
private:
  int fd;
};
```

I have another class, say `Bar`, defined like this:

```cpp
class Bar {
public:
  Bar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      Foo foo(i);
      if (foo.valid) {
        vector_of_foos.push_back(foo);
      }
    }
  }

  std::vector<Foo> vector_of_foos;
};
```

The problem with this is that `push_back` makes a copy of the Foo object, which copies the `fd` property. Then the destructor for the original `Foo` object is called, which closes the file that `fd` points to, rendering `fd` invalid.

Unfortunately I cannot use `emplace_back` since I need to instantiate my `Foo` object *before* adding it to the `vector_of_foos` vector so that I can check the `valid` property.

I have also tried using `std::move` but this still calls the destructor for the original `Foo` object once it goes out of scope which closes the file.

What is the recommended way of managing a resource like this? Should I use an array of smart pointers? Should my `vector_of_foos` be instead a `std::vector<Foo *>` where I maintain a vector of pointers to `Foo` which I allocate dynamically?

Comment: The right way is to move it. The right way to move it is to set `fd` in the moved-from object to an "dummy/empty/invalid" value, so that the destructor doesn't do anything, um, destructive.

Comment: @n.m. How do I move it into the vector? As far as I can tell using `push_back(std::move(foo))` doesn't call either the move constructor or the move assignment operator (I've tried both)

Comment: `ide(std::move(foo))` should call the move constructor. Your class should have a non-default one for this to work. [And it works](https://ideone.com/Du6vV3). Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo` needs a copy constructor and copy assignment operator so it can `dup()` the `fd` of the copied-from object (or, you need to `delete` them so `Foo` objects can't be copied at all, only moved).

When implementing move semantics, after moving the `fd` value from the moved-from object to the moved-to object, you need to update the moved-from object so its `fd` no longer refers to a valid file descriptor.  Simply set it to -1, which is what `open()` and `dup()` return on error.

You don't need your `valid` member at all.  That is a source of error waiting to happen if it ever gets out of sync with your `fd`.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(int i) {
    std::string devname = "/dev/device" + std::to_string(i);
    fd = open(devname.c_str(), O_RDWR);
  }

  Foo(const Foo &src) {
    fd = dup(src.fd);
  }
  // or: Foo(const Foo &) = delete;

  Foo(Foo &&src) : fd(-1) {
    src.swap(*this);
  }

  ~Foo() {
    if (fd != -1) {
      close(fd);
    }
  }

  bool valid() const {
    return (fd != -1); 
  }

  Foo& operator=(Foo rhs) {
    rhs.swap(*this);
    return *this;
  }
  // optional: Foo& operator=(const Foo &) = delete;

  void swap(Foo &other) {
    std::swap(fd, other.fd);
  }

private:
  int fd;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

n.m beat me to the punch, but you need to define a move constructor that 'forgets' about your file descriptor in the moved-from object.  Something like:

```
Foo (Foo &&move_from)
{
    valid = move_from.valid;
    fd = move_from.fd;
    move_from.valid = false;
}
```

Also, delete your copy constructor and copy assignment operator and implement a move-assignment operator.  You then have an object that can be moved but not copied, rather like `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to delete copy constructors altogether (or provide some logic to have two valid instances with different descriptors). If you delete them, compiler will make sure you use move semantics always.

Then, you can declare move constructors, that will perform valid moving:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(int i) {
    valid = false;
    char devname[] = "/dev/device0";
    sprintf(devname, "/dev/device%d", i);
    fd = open(devname, O_RDWR);
    if (fd > 0) {
      valid = true;
    }

  ~Foo() {
    if (valid) {
      close(fd);
    }
  }

  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo(Foo&& other) {
    valid = other.valid;
    fd = other.fd;
    other.valid = false;
  };
  Foo& operator=(Foo&& other) {
    valid = other.valid;
    fd = other.fd;
    other.valid = false;
  };

  bool valid;
private:
  int fd;
};
```

A bit of explanation:

You violated the [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). In short, it says "whenever your class needs a user defined destructor/copy constructor/move constructor, it will most likely the rest of them". Your class does require a destructor, which you provided, but you didn't provide neither copy or move operators, which is a mistake. You have to provide both copy constructor/copy assignment operator (here deleted) and move constructor/move assignment operator.

As to why: compiler is not smart enough to guess what do you need. Ignoring the fact that your class doesn't support move semantics (user-defined destructor prevents implicit creation of move constructors), implicit move constructor is very, very simple. It just calls `std::move` on every class member. And `std::move` for primitive types is also very simple - it just copies that variable, as it's the fastest operation.
It *could* possibly zero the other variable, but that's not necessary. As per definition, the variable must be left in "*unknown, but valid state*". No change to that variable fits this definition.

Comment: In `Foo(const Foo&& other)` and `Foo& operator=(const Foo&& other)`, you need to drop the `const`. Move semantics require non-const objects so members can be updated after being moved.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True

Comment: @RemyLebeau I assumed that `valid` field is used for this purpose, but your answer covers it better ;)